# Portal Achievement Issue - Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, portal

My account on Xbox live says that I haven't gotten the "Vanilla Crazy Cake" Achievement but I actually have completed the achievement and when I load up Portal and look at the achievements in the game it says I have completed it.  Is there a way to get my Xbox live account to "see" the achievement?  If not can I delete the achievement in the game and do it again to see if it gets "seen" by my live account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you should be able to clear Portal's local cache and then it will either have no achievements at all (locally -- Live will be fine) or pick up the ones from Live, I'm not sure how it works.  But yeah, clearing the Portal data off your XBox's HDD should allow you to get the achievement again.  I've never done this on XBox but I have done the equivalent on Steam.

Comment: Hmm.. Aren't achievements stored server side in steam? Is it really possible to reset them?

Comment: As my answer says, you don't reset Steam/Live.  You erase the local data which somehow has gotten the game into the state where it thinks you've got an achievement that's not in Steam/Live.  You can play both Steam and Live games offline, and if the game shows you achievements within the game itself (as Portal does) you will still see which ones you've gotten; it caches it locally and doesn't need to retrieve it from the service.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks i'll give this a shot and see what happens.  btw is this the same Matthew Read from Android Enthusiasts-SE?

Comment: @Daniel You can easily check by looking at his profile's [accounts tab](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/6066/matthew-read?tab=accounts)

Comment: @Daniel That's me :P I hope this works for you.

Comment: @badp Thanks I didn't know you could check that.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks it worked! I just finally got around to finishing the challenges.